# Disable Options on React-Native Text Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textinput

I am using TextInput for a project and wanted to DISABLE any kind of text selection or actions like (cut/copy/paste/share) as shared in the screenshot below.

I am not able find anything in the react-native official documentation

[image]

Comment: use readonly attribute?

Comment: Use caretHidden={true} if you want to disable all operation like Cut Paste Copy. It will also hide your cursor as well.

Answer (score 162):

You should add 2 attributes
`selectTextOnFocus` and `editable`

For example:

```
<TextInput editable={false} selectTextOnFocus={false} />
```

Comment: editable false - i cant even edit the text input now - I need these when i can edit but cannot copy/cut/paste on this text input

Comment: when I give the editable false how can I use TextInput.I want to make copy/paste option disable no need to give editable={false}

Answer (score 27):

**contextMenuHidden** is to disable the user from pasting text into certain fields and to hide context menu.

**Update:**
This hasn’t been included in a release yet. You can always see what release any commit is in by clicking on the [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2dd2529b3ab3ace39136a6e24c09f80ae421a17e) and looking at the tags. so I wouldn't expect it to be on a stable release until 0.55.

```
<TextInput contextMenuHidden={true} />
```

Check the commit here: [Add option to hide context menu for TextInput](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2dd2529b3ab3ace39136a6e24c09f80ae421a17e)

Comment: I'm using react-native v0.54.0 and I couldn't get it work with this.

Comment: @MateoGuzmán Updated the answer.

Comment: Looks like it was put in 55.4 but it doesn't work for Android. Is anyone else able to get this to work on both platforms?

Comment: This method doesn't work on Android. Did you find any solution to prevent Copy/Paste option in android?

Answer (score 24):

Just give your textinput the attribute `editable={false}`

Answer (score 22):

Set [pointerEvents](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents) to none on parent `View` of `TextInput` to disable touch events, consider following example:

```
<View pointerEvents="none">
  <TextInput ... />
</View>
```

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Comment: pointerEvent is not better solution this scenario, add `caretHidden={true}`.

Comment: This solution won't work if you already have the cursor inside the textInput box

Answer (score 3):

You can use a View and use removeClippedSubviews={true} (works with Android) and use contextMenuHidden={true} (works with IOS)

`<View removeClippedSubviews={true}>
  <TextInput contextMenuHidden={true} />
</View>`

Answer (score 0):

Reference from the following issue
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/33697

```
const App = () => {
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState(null);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  return (
    <TextInput 
      selection={selection}
      onSelectionChange={(e) => setSelection(e.nativeEvent.selection)}
      value={text}
      onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
      style={{ alignSelf: 'center', width: 200, marginTop: 50, backgroundColor: 'grey' }} 
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution works for me for avoiding copy/paste. I am clearing keyboard on onTouchEnd event

```
const [text1, setText1] = useState('')
    
const clearClipboard = () =>{
 Clipboard.setString('')
}
    
const onChangeText = (text) =>{
 //For android 12+ clipboard autofill option, dont allow text change more than one char..which means user is typing.
 if(text1.length+1 >= text.length){
  setText1(text)
 }
}
    
<TextInput onChangeText={onChangeText} value={text1} contextMenuHidden={true} onTouchEnd={clearClipboard}></TextInput>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **caretHidden={true}** if you want to disable all operation like Cut Paste Copy. It will also hide your cursor as well

Comment: Checked Android - all operations *still appear* as usual if you select some text.

Comment: How can I do this without hide the cursor?

Answer (score -4):

This trick worked for me. Here I am using NativeBase. Keep this `<TextInput>` inside a `<Item>` tag.  Now the selection property should not work.

code sample attached below.

```
<Item>
<Input
  value={this.props.call_state.destination}
  onChangeText={text => this.props.setDestination(text)}
  returnKeyType={"done"}
  keyboardType={"numeric"}
/>
</Item>
```

You should install nativebase first and then import `{Item}` from native-base in your component

Comment: This is probably due to a bug in nativebase, since you should be able to select/copy/paste a text input by default.