# How to disable cut/copy/paste in TextInput in react native with not hidden cursor?

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

Could anybody tell me how to disable cut/copy/paste fucntionality in TextInput in react native? I tried used

```js
contextMenuHidden={true}, editable={false}, selectTextOnFocus={false}, contextMenuHidden={true}
```

but nothing to helped me. Only `caretHidden={true}` helped me, but I need cursor visibele, so I can't use `caretHidden={true}`. Have anybody any ideas for disable cut/copy/paste but with saving visible cursor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Options on React-Native Text Input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42883864/disable-options-on-react-native-text-input)

Comment: it's similiar, but nothing  from that answers  helped me

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently, solved with `contextMenuHidden` prop, works on Android and iOS.

> If `true`, context menu is hidden. The default value is `false`.
>
> **TYPE**: bool

```
<TextInput contextMenuHidden = { true } />
```

From [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/next/textinput#contextmenuhidden).